# Formula code in Word 2016 [mac]

Tags: worksheet-function, macbook-pro-retina, microsoft-word-2016

I'm currently making an invoice template in word, but I'm fighting with the formula code which is used.

Currently this is my table: 
[image: Table]

But, the number of rows wil depend on the days which I've worked. Right now, I have to manually alter the code to edit the cell-references of the row-totals if I create more rows. And when I update the cells, the total amount gets higher and higher (it keeps multiplying or something, but I don't know what it does exactly)

The VAT number (the 21%, which is a table with a invisible left side) has the bookmark 'VAT'. The Subtotal has the bookmark 'Subtotal'.

[image: Table with codes]

Is there an easier way to do this? To let the cell-reference automatically change or change the formula code in a way that naming the cell-references isn't needed?

Thanks in advance :)

Other images of what I have:
Row totals (b1 to 7 is the cell reference of the hours):
`{=b7*20}`

VAT: `{=Subtotal*VAT}`

Total: `{=VAT+Subtotal}`

I asked the question before on stack overflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316313/formula-code-in-word-2015-mac)), where I got the following answer for the VAT number using the bookmarks, but this code gives a syntax error in my word 2016 for mac. There it was advised to ask the question here.

```
{ = { REF Subtotal } * { REF VAT } }
```

---

---

Images with answer-possibilities:

[image: Answer]

[image: Answer]

Comment: Word 2015 doesn't exist.

Comment: My bad, 2016 :)

Comment: NP. Now I can fix the tags ;)

Comment: @DavePostill: re the tags, unfortunately the latest Mac and Windows versions now have the same number, i.e. 2016, even though they are still very different products. I assume that may also apply to Office and other Office components. Defining tags etc. is a new area for me here - let me know if I can help.

Comment: @bibadia I see that in my second image it cut off the 'total' row; in the VAT cell it should only display the VAT amount (usually 21% of the subtotal). The total cell should have the subtotal plus vat combined, so, like it says, the total amount that should be paid. About the values: If I use {=VAT}, then it gives me (at first) 0,21. Even if I split the column and have only the '21'-cell bookmarked, without the %-sign. If I update the cell, it doubles it (so it becomes 0,42), and so on. If I use {=Subtotal}, it gives a value higher; The subtotal is 170 and the given value is 184,50.

Comment: Updating it gives the same value at subtotal. So that's were it goes wrong already. At both VAT and Subtotal the whole cell is bookmarked (but with VAT without the %). Currently don't have formula's at VAT and Total (only subtotal has a formula; the sum of all above, which is consistently correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you need like this, as long as your VAT rate (21%) is in a cell in the table, not in a cell in a table nested in this table (which is what I thought you were describing originally).

Remove the bookmarks "VAT" and "Subtotal"

In every row in Column A, insert the following field code. All the { } have to be the field code brace pairs that you can insert using cmd-F9/fn-cmd-F9.

```
{ SEQ row \h }
```

Change the formulas for D2 to D7 to

```
{ ={ QUOTE B{ SEQ row \c } }*20 \#"€#.##0,00;(€#.##0,00)" }
```

Change the Subtotal formula in D9 to

```
{ =SUM(ABOVE) \#"€#.##0,00;(€#.##0,00)" }{ SET Subtotal "D{ SEQ row \c }" }
```

Assuming that the VAT % is in column C and is actually the % (i.e. says "21%"), somewhere in the VAT row that the user should not type into (e.g. the cell that actually says "VAT", put

```
{ SET VAT "C{ SEQ row \c }" }
```

Change the calculation in the last cell of that row to

```
{ ={ Subtotal }*{ VAT } }
```

Change the total calculation to

```
{ ={ Subtotal }+({ Subtotal }*{ VAT }) }
```

Then update all the fields.

You can leave a lot of the spaces out of the above formulas if you prefer.

(Of course it is up to you, but "€.0,00;(€.0,0)" or "€ .0,00;(€ .0,0)" may work better as a numeric picture here - the "." does not actually have to be in the "thousands separator" position to work properly.)

This should allow you to insert additional invoice rows - probably most easily done by copying an existing row.

Comment: If I fill it out like you say, I get row-totals as '0,00' and '0,25' (but they should be 0,25*20€=5€ and 1*20€=20€). The subtotal seems to be correct (working with the incorrect row-totals). But, I get a VAT value of 503,50 and a total of 503,25. Used 3 rows in this case: 0,25, 0,25 and 1 hours. Is it possible to share a mockup? With your method?

Comment: Added images to post :)

Comment: (1) I have omitted the "*20" in the D2-D7 formulas - now fixed. 

(2) You also either need { SEQ row \h } in cell A1 (next to "Description") or change the one in A2 to  { SEQ row \r2 \h }. 

(3) I have temporarily put my sample .docx at https://www.dropbox.com/s/38lljx0zi9njqxf/20160213%20tableformula.docx?dl=0

Comment: Your sample works perfectly! I changed the stuff you said in my own document and now the subtotal and the row totals work. Only the VAT amount is '0' and the total-cell is empty. Is there anything else wrong with the example I have in the start post?

Comment: Oh, I when I do this: {=VAT} it gives me the value '0'. Maybe that's what's messing everything up? {=Subtotal} gives 0 too.

Comment: (darn, can't edit, haha) The VAT% is in (counting from the left) in the second column. Every cell-line is visible in my latest example in the start post.

Comment: Changing the code doesn't do anything: referencing {={VAT}} gives me the value '0'. After filling out your code, and toggling the code again, it gives me "{SET VAT "B6"}". (The code I've used: { SET VAT "B{ SEQ row \c }" }). Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Referencing Subtotal "{={Subtotal}}", gives me '0' too. Checking the code gives me {=D6}. But that seems weird, because the cell with subtotal should be D7?

Comment: Maybe this can help: temporary link to my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/raetkwujkms0tu0/invoice_wip.docx?dl=0

Comment: Yes, a few things wee still missing (you need those SEQ fields all the way down column A, at least as far as you need to make row references.The code to set the VAT cell address would typically be better off in column A as well, assuming that the actual VAT % is more likely to be edited than the text "VAT". Have a look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayvpu7729ihnxmz/invoice_wip1.docx?dl=0

Comment: Ah, so the SEQ row \h must be filled out for the column A subtotal, -vat and -total fields as well? And you didn't put any code in the cell with '21%' then?

Comment: Correct. The SEQ row \h fields are just there to number the rows, so that you can form the cell addresses you need to reference the other cells.

Comment: OK, understood! Thanks a lot for your help, I have a working doc now!